# How can i configure Mysql in Xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a problem with Mysql and Xampp. I installed Xampp and, with the package, it was installed Mysql too, but I installed Mysql many months ago.

So, the problem is when I try to "start" it. It doesn't work because of Mysql is already running on port 3306.

What I have to do for "activate" Mysql in Xampp if I have another Mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the port of Mysql Server in XAMPP. Here is the solution.
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-the-port-of-a-MySQL-server-in-XAMPP